# What's the ideal order of checks for early bailout when processing files with Perl?

Tags: performance, perl, file-io, filter

Parsing a directory tree with hundreds of thousands of of files looking for valid (non-empty, readable) log files. What is the most efficient order of tests for early bail?

Here's an example I use as a file::find preprocessor stage and, being new to Perl, I wonder what tests are slowests / redundant / inefficiently ordered?

```
sub filter {
    my $nicename = substr( $File::Find::dir, $_pathLength );
    my @clean;
    my $filecount = my $dircount = 0;
    foreach (@_) {
        next unless -R $_;           # readable
        next unless -f _ || -d _;    # file or dir.
        next if ( $_ =~ m/^\./ );    # ignore files/folders starting with a period
        if ( -f _ ) {                # regular file
            next unless ( my $size = -s _ );    # does it have a size?
            next unless ( $_ =~ m/([^.]+)$/ )[0] eq $_log_file_ext;    # correct file extension?
            next if exists( $_previousRun{ $_ . " ($size)" } );        # don't add files we've already processed
            $filecount++;
        } elsif ( -d _ ) {                                             # dir
            $dircount++;
        }
        push( @clean, $_ );
    }
    $_fileCount += $filecount;
    $_dirCount  += $dircount;
    Utils::logit("'$nicename' contains $filecount new files and $dircount folders to explore.");
    return @clean;
}
```

Any info you can provide on Perls internals and behaviours would be useful to me.

At the very end I run some specific checks for "regular file" and "directory". Are there other things I should check for and avoid adding to my clean list?

Comment: Attention: before you open the file, most of the information you checked might change (race condition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rough rule of thumb, 'going to disk' it the most expensive thing you'll be doing.

So when trying to optimise IO based:

- First, discard anything you can based on name/location. (e.g. 'does filename contain a .')
- Then discard based on file attributes - coalesce if you can into a single `stat` call, because then you're making a single IO.
- And then do anything else.

I'm at least fairly sure that your `-s` `-d` `-f` etc. will be triggering stat() operations each time they go. (Which will probably get cached, so it doesn't hurt that much). But you do also test `-f` and `-d` twice - once to do the `next unless` and again to do the `if`

But you might find you can do a single `stat` and get most of the metadata you're interested in:
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html

In the grand scheme of things though - I wouldn't worry about it too much. Your limiting factor will be disk IO, and the odd additional `stat` or regular expressions won't make much difference to the overall speed.

Comment: (apologies. linebreak = "add comment", it seems, with only 5 minutes grace. So here's the continuation): I'm not really worried about the performance of this routine, I guess I asked the question mostly to learn a bit more about Perl. Specifically, the language have so many smart and useful default behaviours, I'd like to see where I'm doing redundant work. The duplicate -f and -d check you point out is a good example (though, maybe more a fs question than a Perl one) - what, other than files and dirs, are there to worry about? Is it important to be this specific?

Comment: Well, there's some edge cases - symbolic links, character special files, device files. But in the grand scheme of things... you probably do cover everything if you look for files and directories. Special files will be a subset. I think you'll probably do fine if you just assume 'not directory' is equivalent to 'file'. Either it'll `open` and you can read it, or it won't and it's a moot point.

Comment: Oh, you also don't appear to make use of `$nicename` - you will probably find that some combination of `$File::Find::dir` and `$File::Find::name` (And $_) will do what you want already.

Comment: Thanks for the additions! $nicename _is_ used (see second-to-last line) for logging / visualization. It simply holds the "local" hierarchy of folders, excluding the long path from the system root. It keeps the output readable and me sane. :)